# Configure WebDriverIO with BrowserMobProxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver, browsermob

Does anyone have a proper example on how to configure [BrowserMobProxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) with [WebDriverIO](http://webdriver.io/)? This is so I can capture network traffic. I previously had it working with [WebDriverJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverjs), which is essentially a deprecated version of [WebDriverIO](http://webdriver.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code to do that. Make sure your `browsermob proxy` and `selenium server` is running. Then copy paste below code in a `test.js` file and put it in `webdriverio` installed folder. From `cmd` go to that folder and run `node test.js` . `stuff.har` should be generated where `test.js` is located.

```
var Proxy = require('browsermob-proxy').Proxy
    , webdriverio = require("./node_modules/webdriverio/")
    , fs = require('fs')
    , proxy = new Proxy()
;

proxy.cbHAR('search.yahoo.com', doSeleniumStuff, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {

            console.error('ERR: ' + err);
        } else {

            fs.writeFileSync('stuff.har', data, 'utf8');


        }
});

function doSeleniumStuff(proxy, cb) {

    var browser = webdriverio.remote({
        host: 'localhost'
        , port: 4444
        , desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'firefox', seleniumProtocol: 'WebDriver', proxy: { httpProxy: proxy } }
    });

    browser
        .init()
        .url("http://search.yahoo.com")
        .setValue("#yschsp", "javascript")
        .submitForm("#sf")
        .end().then(cb);        

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to capture the network traffic, then there is one more way to do it.

Webdriverio allows you to use [Chrome Dev Tools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

Please read [webdriverio blog](https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/09/16/devtools.html)

This is one of the examples on how to use chrome dev tools along with webdriverio, do let me know in case you need more help.

```
const { remote } = require('webdriverio')

    let browser;

    (async () => {
        browser = await remote({
            automationProtocol: 'devtools',
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        })

        await browser.url('https://webdriver.io')

        await browser.call(async () => {
            const puppeteerBrowser = browser.getPuppeteer()
            const page = (await puppeteerBrowser.pages())[0]
            await page.setRequestInterception(true)
            page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
                if (interceptedRequest.url().endsWith('webdriverio.png')) {
                    return interceptedRequest.continue({
                        url: 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10379601/29446482-04f7036a-841f-11e7-9872-91d1fc2ea683.png'
                    })
                }

                interceptedRequest.continue()
            })
        })

        // continue with WebDriver commands
        await browser.refresh()
        await browser.pause(2000)

        await browser.deleteSession()
    })().catch(async (e) => {
        console.error(e)
        await browser.deleteSession()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I had no luck solving this problem using `browsermob proxy` (AFAIK it wasn't updated in a while)

I created a small npm module to capture selenium tests as HAR files - https://www.npmjs.com/package/har-recorder

I took @Raulster24 suggestion and implemented it using the Chrome Dev Tools Protocol - https://github.com/loadmill/har-recorder/blob/master/index.js