# How to catch the response data in UI automation

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webdriver-io

I am using `WebDriverIO` for the UI Automation and I am trying to automate for a **login** page.

When I click the `Login` button, `*.com/user/login` request will get trigger in the background. Here, I want to catch that `*.com/user/login` call response, because I have to get a token from the response to proceed to next test case.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture network traffic using `BrowserMob`, `selenium server` and below code. For more details , refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203022/configure-webdriverio-with-browsermobproxy/36784159#36784159) answer. Then parse `stuff.har` , to get desired result. `Har` file is in json format.

```
var Proxy = require('browsermob-proxy').Proxy
    , webdriverio = require("./node_modules/webdriverio/")
    , fs = require('fs')
    , proxy = new Proxy()
;

proxy.cbHAR('webdriver.io', doSeleniumStuff, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {

            console.error('ERR: ' + err);
        } else {

            fs.writeFileSync('stuff.har', data, 'utf8');


        }
});

function doSeleniumStuff(proxy, cb) {

    var browser = webdriverio.remote({
        host: 'localhost'
        , port: 4444
        , desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'firefox', seleniumProtocol: 'WebDriver', proxy: { httpProxy: proxy } }
    });

    browser
        .init()
        .url("http://webdriver.io")
        //.setValue("#yschsp", "javascript")
        //.submitForm("#sf")
        .end().then(cb);        

}
```